# USB Amp disabled OS' volume change

Tags: audio, sound-volume

I'm utilizing an external sound amplifier over usb to enhance the audio output of my passive shelf speakers. However, I've encountered an issue with the volume control when I set the sound output to SPDIF (the specific name of the amplifier). In macOS, adjusting the volume control has no effect.

Essentially, the amplifier takes control of the volume adjustment, rendering the macOS volume control ineffective. Consequently, I am compelled to rely on the physical knob on the amplifier to adjust the volume.

[image: System Settings > Sound]

Additionally, when I select the amplifier as the output device, the Output Volume option in the system settings becomes disabled.

Do you have any suggestions for software solutions that would allow me to regain control of the volume settings through my operating system?

I'm using **Mac Mini** with M2 chip and my amp is **Fosi Audio Da-2120A**

Comment: Do you have two different entries for the USB Amp?  One can be controlled by the volume and the other can’t?

Comment: It's hard to find any real info on this amp, but I'm wondering if it's actually not truly class-compliant. From what I can gather, it's a mish-mash of old & new technologies… the op amps themselves are actually from [1979](https://www.ti.com/product/NE5532). [no, that's not a typo] & long past their sell-by date.

Comment: @Allan nope there's a single input for usb. here's the detailed info for the amp https://tinyurl.com/3dcwmypf

Comment: I didn’t ask that.  I asked if there was more than one device listed for the amp

Comment: nope there isn't one, the other ones are listed my monitor and audio interface (input only)